# How to spell sql server rank function NTILE?

Tags: sql-server

I've never used this rank function in SQL SERVER.
My questions:

1. how to spell this 'NTILE'?
2. It's sql standard or only exists in MSSQL T-SQL?

I'm not asking how to use it because I can find it through:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx

Comment: Then what *are* you asking?

Comment: Here is an article about NTILE: http://database-programmer.blogspot.sg/2010/11/really-cool-ntile-window-function.html   It says Postgresql, MSSQL, and Oracle have it.

Comment: It's not available in MySQL because it is a windowed function (which MySQL doesn't support)

Comment: Are you asking how to *pronounce* `NTILE`? Because asking how to *spell* a word when you're asking in a written medium is a little... confusing?

Comment: If it is about pronunciation, "ntile" is like "nth" (as in 1st, 2nd, 3rd, nth). It is a general version of "quartile" (the fourth part). So "EN TILE"

Comment: Yes, it's about pronunciation. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spell it as N + Tile

Write it as N + Tile

Read it as N + Tile

Pronounce it as N + Tile

Learn it as N + Tile

Understand it as N + Tile

Never Forget it as N + Tile

Hope you got N-thralled